# C# Modem and AT Command

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice, modem, at-command

Alright, my brain has shorted out on me. What I'm trying to do is write a program that allows me to call my computer, after so many rings the computer answers. At this point I would be able to speak to my computer and utilize the computers voice recognition abilities. However, my computer is not receiving my voice via the telephone as a "mic in" audio source. More than likely it is because the COM4 port is what the modem is using as its relay source.

Currently, I can place a phone call from my computer and receive a phone call from my computer. The computer is currently acting as a glorified telephone. Two users can call one another back and forth but the PC just sits there like a third person on an awkward date. I'm wanting the computer to take a more active role in listening to the caller.

Regardless, I cannot seem to hammer out the code that would allow me to get the computer to listen to the callers voice. I'm just breaking the ice on the AT commands so please go gentle with me.

Below is the code from from1. Any assistance would be great. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Drawing; 
    using System.Windows.Forms; 
    using System.IO.Ports; 
    using System.Threading; 
    using System.IO; 

namespace VoiceModem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte[] buffer; 
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SerialPort modemPort;
        int bufferLoc;
        string strBuf;
        FileStream file; 
        StreamWriter logfile;


        //note to self: the max port speed is listed at 115200
        private void btnCALL_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string PHONENUMBER = "ATD=" + this.textBox1.Text + "\r";
            //File.Close("raw.txt", FileMode.Create);   
            //C:\Documents and Settings\Commander\Desktop
            file = File.Open("raw.txt", FileMode.Create);
            logfile = File.CreateText("log.txt");
            buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];
            modemPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 112500, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            modemPort.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;
            modemPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(modemPort_DataReceived);
            modemPort.Open();
            modemPort.Write("AT\r"); //OK
            modemPort.Write("ATA\r"); //ANSWERING IN VOICE MODE  *** NO CARRIER
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            modemPort.Write("AT+FCLASS=8\r"); ///this should be voice here
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            modemPort.Write(PHONENUMBER); //DIAL number that D equals
          //  modemPort.Write("ATH\r"); //HANG UP IN VOICE MODE   //ERROR 
            //modemPort.Write("AT+VSM=1\r"); 
         //   modemPort.Write("AT+VTX\r"); //VOICE TRANSMIT MODE  //ERROR
        //    modemPort.Write("AT+VLS=5\r"); 
            Thread.Sleep(500);
           modemPort.Write("AT+VRX\r"); //VOICE RECEIVE MODE  
           Thread.Sleep(500);
           modemPort.Write("AT+VLS=3+RX\r");
            //VLS 
            //0 - Telephone Line Select (Go on hook) 
            //2 - Speakers 
            //3 - Microphone 
            //4 - Telephone Line Select + Samples routed to/from Speakers/Mic in TX/RX modes 
            //6 - Speakerphone
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //C:\Documents and Settings\Commander\Desktop
            file = File.Open("raw.txt", FileMode.Create); 
                logfile = File.CreateText("log.txt"); 
            buffer = new byte[10*1024]; 
                modemPort = new SerialPort("COM4",112500, Parity.None, 8,StopBits.One); 
                modemPort.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout; 
                modemPort.DataReceived+= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(modemPort_DataReceived); 
                modemPort.Open(); 
                modemPort.Write("AT\r"); //OK
                //modemPort.Write("ATA\r"); //ANSWERING IN VOICE MODE  *** NO CARRIER
                modemPort.Write("AT+FCLASS=8\r");
          //  "ATD=6022626151;\r"


                //modemPort.Write(this.textBox1.Text);


            //ATD4412345679;
                //Dmn   ATDmn will dial a phone number where m is the modifier: L, W, ,, ;, @, or S. 
            //It will dial the telephone number n.

            // string str = "Hello " + userName + ". Today is " + date + ".";
            string PHONENUMBER = "ATD=" + this.textBox1.Text + "\r";

                Thread.Sleep(500);
                modemPort.Write(PHONENUMBER); //DIAL number that D equals

                Thread.Sleep(500);
                modemPort.Write("ATH\r"); //HANG UP IN VOICE MODE   //ERROR 
                //modemPort.Write("AT+VSM=1\r"); 
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                modemPort.Write("AT+VLS=?\r");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                modemPort.Write("AT+VTX\r"); //VOICE TRANSMIT MODE  //ERROR
                //modemPort.Write("AT+VLS=1\r"); 
                Thread.Sleep(500); 
                buffer = new byte[10*1024];
                modemPort.Write("AT+VRX\r"); //VOICE RECEIVE MODE  
                //modemPort.Write("AT+VRX\r");
        }



         void modemPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args) 
            { 
                int x = modemPort.BytesToRead; 
                modemPort.Read(buffer,0,x); 
                file.Write(buffer,0,x); 
                logfile.WriteLine(x.ToString()+args.EventType.ToString()); 
            } 


        private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {


            modemPort.Close(); 
                file.Close(); 
                logfile.Close(); 

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            //Form2.show();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("raw.txt");
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.richTextBox2.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("log.txt");
        }

        private void NUMBER1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //tBox1.Text += "a";
            this.textBox1.Text += "1";
        }

        private void NUMBER2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "2";

        }

        private void NUMBER3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "3";

        }

        private void NUMBER4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "4";

        }

        private void NUMBER5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "5";

        }

        private void NUMBER6_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "6";

        }

        private void NUMBER7_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "7";

        }

        private void NUMBER8_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "8";

        }

        private void NUMBER9_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "9";

        }

        private void NUMBER0_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += "0";

        }

        private void btnREDIAL_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];
            modemPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 112500, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            modemPort.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;
            modemPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(modemPort_DataReceived);
            modemPort.Open();
            modemPort.Write("AT\r"); //OK
            modemPort.Write("ATDL\r"); //OK

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Focus();

        }

        private void btnANSWER_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //C:\Documents and Settings\Commander\Desktop
            file = File.Open("raw.txt", FileMode.Create);
            logfile = File.CreateText("log.txt");
            buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];
            modemPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 112500, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            modemPort.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;
            modemPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(modemPort_DataReceived);
            modemPort.Open();
            modemPort.Write("AT\r"); //OK
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            modemPort.Write("ATA\r"); //ANSWERING then gives beep-boops
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            //modemPort.Write("AT+VLS=1");
            //modemPort.Write("AT+FCLASS=8\r");
            // string str = "Hello " + userName + ". Today is " + date + ".";
           // string PHONENUMBER = "ATD=" + this.textBox1.Text + "\r";
           // modemPort.Write(PHONENUMBER); //DIAL number that D equals
           //modemPort.Write("ATH\r"); //HANG UP IN VOICE MODE   //ERROR 
            //modemPort.Write("AT+VSM=1\r"); 
            //modemPort.Write("AT+++\r");// disconnects data mode to allow for voice mode
            //voice mode is activated using ata
            modemPort.Write("AT+VRX\r");
            //modemPort.Write("AT+VTX\r"); //VOICE TRANSMIT MODE  //ERROR
            //modemPort.Write("AT+VLS=1\r");
           // modemPort.Write("ATH\r"); //HANG UP IN VOICE MODE   //ERROR
           //modemPort.Write("AT+VRX\r");
            //modemPort.Write("ATA\r"); //answer the call
        }

        private void btnHANGUP_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            modemPort.Close();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            //int iPhone = 7065551212;
            //string strPhone = string.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", iPhone);



           // this.textBox1.Mask = "(999) 000-0000";
        }

        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Reset the colors and selection of the TextBox after focus is lost.
            string x = textBox1.Text;
            double y = Double.Parse(x);
            textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", y);

            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            textBox1.Select(0, 0);
        }






        /*
         * ACTIVE PROFILE:
    E0 L1 M1 Q0 T V1 X4 &C1 &D2 &G0 &P0 
    S00:000 S01:000 S02:043 S03:013 S04:010 S05:008 S06:002 S07:060 S08:002
    S10:014 S12:050 S29:070

    STORED PROFILE 0:
    E0 L1 M1 Q0 T V1 X4 &C1 &D2 &G0 &P0 
    S00:000 S02:043 S06:002 S07:050 S08:002 S10:014 S12:050 S29:070
         * 
         * 
         * DIAG <2A4D3263 0=10>

    DIAG <2A4D3263 1=0>

    DIAG <2A4D3263 60=1>
         * */





    } 



}
```

Comment: +1. Haven't see the `AT` command since 1996. Ah .. the memories. I wonder if there are posts out there about `zmodem` and `kermit` protocol.

Comment: I agree, it's like assembler old school but really sharp when it's working! I'm telling ya, my VR (voice recognition) program would rock your world. Currently, it controls almost every aspect of my lab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is an IVR system.  Here is a [link to an article on why most modems will not work with IVR systems](http://www.ivrsoft.com/voice-modems.htm).  Even if you got the modem to work you have a lot of development effort to get a basic IVR system to work.  Voxeo has a [free 2 port IVR system for developers called Prophecy](http://www.voxeo.com/prophecy/).  This IVR system uses open W3C standards like [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/) and [CCXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) to program your voice application and has a decent speech recognition and text-to-speech (TTS) bundled in it.  Since you are using C# I would recommend looking at the open-source project [VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/) which greatly simplifies developing voice applications that will run on Prophecy (or any VoiceXML compatible system) using C# and ASP.NET MVC.

Prophecy's telephony interface is SIP, so the cost will be getting a VoIP gateway that will translate your analog telephone line to SIP.  The FXO gateway mentioned in another answer may work if it supports SIP. Voxeo supports [AudioCodes MP-114 which is a 4 port analog system](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001BWORZ0) that retails for about $395. You may be able to find a used one on eBay for less. They use to support Dialogic cards with a software VoIP Gateway but it turned out to be a support nightmare and caused a lot of issues with speech recognition so they dropped it. You need pretty decent voice quality to get speech recognition to work correctly which is another reason not to use a modem.  It can be challenging getting a VoIP gateway to work correctly that has analog input but I have had success using the AudioCodes product. The other advantage to AudioCodes is that it is supported by Voxeo and their support is free and excellent.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded to this. I continued in my research and contacted a rep at Zoomtel and learned that the AT commands are simply used to open/set the modem. If I need the incoming voice to do anything else I need to utilize other software products to accomplish that. So, in short, there is really nothing incorrect about my code, however, I will not be able to accomplish the computer listening via the use of AT commands exclusively.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with a modem (stands for MOdulator/DEModulator).  These are designed to turn digital communication into analog for transmittal down phone lines and then changing the analog signal back to digital.  What you want is a voice processing card.

The ones I am most familiar with are Dialogic, but that was about 10 years ago.  I did a quick search and the Dialogic Diva 2 Port Analog card is the sort of thing you want.  You can also search for telephony boards or cards.  I saw another card from a company called Digium.

The voice processing card will fit into the PCI slot of a PC motherboard.  You plug analog phone lines into the card.  Through the board's API you can interact with the phone line as if the computer was a phone.  10 years ago you could detect human voice frequency, but voice recognition was in its infancy.  You can play sound files over the phone line ("Press 1 for customer service") and then respond to the touch tones (aka DTMF) for program control.

You could write anything from a simple voice mail up to a pretty neat multi-line phone system all on a PC.  I'm sure the APIs for the Dialogic cards as increased dramatically in power.  That's where I would look next.  The Modem simply will not do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will look into some of the feedback that you have offered but I'm wondering if I need to drop that much money on something? Seeings how my wallet didn't just explode I'm building with relatively inexpensive parts. Interestingly enough the computer's default automatically recognized the modem as a fax/data modem. So, I had to hack it up a bit to and now the PC recognizes voice as well. That's the only way I was able to get it to accept a "voice" mode was by rewriting some of the dll's and drivers. I have a lot more I want to relay but I'm running out of chara

Comment: Yes, you need a telephony card, that is one approach. the other approach is to get VOIP telephone service. Then your computer can answer the phone call because it comes in as IP traffic over the data network. You might want to check out Asterisk - http://www.asterisk.org/ - to get some ideas.

Comment: This overview of Microsoft SpeechServer 2007 may also be a helpful introduction to the Telephony and VOIP concepts - http://bit.ly/L72FmY    SO keeps messing up the full URL -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb858353(v=office.12)

Answer (score 2):

What answers the phone is a modem; it only communicates with other modems.  It doesn't support answering the phone and passing along any audio to a program.

Comment: check this out here: http://www.zoomtel.com/products/dial_up_internal.html#internal_3030 it allows for voice mail and that is a PCI card. It is possible to take in voice, record it, play it back. I'm simply trying to work with the AT commands to route the audio in a way that can record. Even if I could quick record, then playback, the audio would be a readable thing. What do you think?

Comment: The modem you link does not process the sound, it acts as a pass-through device and forwards the audio to the sound card.

Comment: Everything described to do what you want to do is an external device that handles the voice/audio independently (i.e. no audio comes to the computer for processing).  This is drastically different than what you described in your post.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [FXO gateway](http://www.3cx.com/PBX/FXS-FXO.html), that will let you turn the [POTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) signal in to something your computer can use. You can get low end consumer devices in the [$50-70 range](https://www.google.com/search?q=fxo#q=fxo&hl=en&sa=X&tbs=p_ord%3ap&tbm=shop&prmd=imvnsz).